# How to redirect file IO for a specific program?

Tags: python, c++, file, io-redirection

I'm using some IM(Instant Messaging) program. When I want to send a photo, it's very inconvenient to delete metadata. As a result, I'm considering to write a program that redirect the photo to the photo which is removed metadata.(I still want to keep the metadata in the local computer)
The basic idea is:

1. Get control of a program
2. Every time the program wants to read an photo (filtered by extension)
3. Copy the photo to another location and remove its metadata (Already implemented)
4. Redirect to the photo which has been removed metadata
5. (After the IO) Delete the photo

Is there any way to implement this in C++ or python?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is possible.  You'll have much better luck just filtering out the metadata within your own program.

Comment: Or maybe create a virtual filesystem that returns metadata-stripped versions when trying to access images.